# Error message vsim-3171 keeps popping up in Modelsim DE 2021.1 even though it was solved in Modelsim ME 10.2c

Tags: system-verilog, modelsim, microsemi-fpga, systemverilog-assertions

I have a test bench where I'm using a SystemVerilog **bind** construct. My test bench follows a similar organization to the one described [at this link](https://www.systemverilog.io/sva-basics)

Every time I run it, error vsim-3171 shows up. I came across a document that states that the issue was [solved in Modelsim ME 10.2c (2013)](https://www.microsemi.com/document-portal/doc_download/132821-modelsim-me-10-2c-release-notes). I'm using Modelsim DE 2021.1 but the issue keeps popping up.

Answer (score 1):

The issue associated to **vsim-3171** goes away after the work library is refreshed as shown below

`vlog -work work_lib -refresh -force_refresh`